# Parsing char array into struct in C++

Tags: arrays, pointers, data-structures, char

I am using a library [RF24Mesh](https://github.com/TMRh20/RF24Mesh) to communicate between Raspberry Pi and Arduino via nRF24l01+. And I am trying to compose a payload message, but I am getting different errors.

```
#include "RF24Mesh/RF24Mesh.h"
#include <RF24/RF24.h>
#include <RF24Network/RF24Network.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

using namespace std;

...

struct payload_t {
  char message[32];
};

...

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char messageSend[32];  //The combined message, ready for sending
  char splittedMessage[3][16];  //The parts to be combined

  ...

  //This is example for splitted message, it is actually read from a file
  //and the strings are not null terminated
  splittedMessage = {{"id", "func", "value"}};

  ...

  //This combines the rows of splittedMessage[][] into messageSend[]
  memcpy(messageSend, splittedMessage[1], strlen(splittedMessage[1]));
  memcpy(&messageSend[strlen(splittedMessage[1])], splittedMessage[2], strlen(splittedMessage[2]));
  memcpy(&messageSend[strlen(splittedMessage[1]) + strlen(splittedMessage[2])], splittedMessage[3], strlen(splittedMessage[3]));
  memcpy(&messageSend[strlen(splittedMessage[1]) + strlen(splittedMessage[2]) + strlen(splittedMessage[3])], "\n", 5);

  printf("messageSend: %s\n", messageSend);

  payload_t payload = { messageSend };
  RF24NetworkHeader header(4, 'M');
  network.write(header, &payload, sizeof(payload));
```

The above code's error is:

> gateway1.cpp:76:38: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

When I try changing: `payload_t payload = { messageSend };` to `payload_t payload = { &messageSend };`
I get:

> gateway1.cpp:76:39: warning: missing braces around initializer for
>   ‘char [32]’ [-Wmissing-braces] 
>   gateway1.cpp:76:39: error: invalid
>   conversion from ‘char (*)[32]’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]

76 is the `payload_t payload = { messageSend };` line.

I tried different things with pointers (random things), but it doesn't work. The only way the message is send is: `payload_t payload = { "someMessage" };`

and:

`payload_t payload = { messageSend[0], messageSend[1], messageSend[2]... };`

Comment: I think you should give up initializing and "assign" the data using `strcpy`.

Comment: Do you think that would copy the characters into the `payload.message`? You must memcpy.

Comment: Use proper (de)serialisation, not casting `char []` into a `struct`! Your code is an invitation to various forms of _undefined behaviour_ and _implementation defined behaviour_.

Comment: **And this is not C!**

Comment: It's hard to evaluate your error messages when we cannot determine how the line numbers relate to your source.

Comment: This: `splittedMessage = {{"id", "func", "value"}}` is not correct for the declared type of `splittedMessage`.  Drop one pair of braces to fix that.

Comment: This: `strlen(splittedMessage[1])` (and similar) is not correct if indeed the elements of `splittedMessage` are not null-terminated strings, as comments in your code indicate is the real-life case.  Since the array dimensions are static, however, perhaps you mean `sizeof(splittedMessage[1])`.  Or maybe you really want to just define a macro representing this size, and to use it consistently.

Comment: On the third hand, if you really do have null-terminated strings, and you are certain that the combined lengths will fit in your buffer (which the declared type of  `splittedMessage` does *not* itself ensure) then `strcat()` would be a much simpler way to do what you appear to be trying to do with those `memcpy()` calls.

Comment: The elements of 'splittedMessage[][]' are not null terminated, but the 'messageSend[]' array is (last 'memcpy' line). Thanks for the 'strcat()' suggestion JohnBollinger, it will save me some code if I change the function that writes to the 'splittedMessage[]' array. But the problem is that the 'payload' struct doesn't accept the 'messageSend' array.

Comment: I tried memcpy() and it worked, thanks.